# spring boot KafkaListener with mulitple group ids

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "test, groupId = "G1")
  public void receiveMessage(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key,
      @Payload final String message) {
    doStuff();
  }
```

I have 6 partitions and want to create 6 consumer in same group, lets say in one machine. 
how can I achieve it ?
1.by deploying 6 instances of app
2.by creating 6 consumers in same app (duplicate code)
any alternatives/suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the same `consumer group`, there is just enough to configure a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` for an appropriate `concurrency` configuration property:

```
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency = 6
```

See Spring Kafka [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_concurrentmessagelistenercontainer) for more information what and how that `concurrency` option means.

Comment: In the next release (2.2), you will be able to override the container factory's `concurrency` on the `@KafkaListener` annotation

Comment: this should help per consumer level : final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory
        = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(2);

Comment: Right, but that's already not a Boot matter. Although we still can do that to override an auto-configured one...

Answer (score 1):

- You can use customized KafkaListener, because use default KafkaListener must to specified a groupId in your @KafkaListener Annotation or in your application.yml/properties file. like following codes, use UUID to generate multi groupIds.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }
}
```

Comment: different groupId for different java instance

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55661387/edit) more explanation to your answer

Comment: @mechnicov I added more explain